# How to change the backgorundColor of BasicTextField in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

In case of a `TextField` we can change the `backgroundColor` of the text field as follows

```
TextField(
    value = text.value,
    onValueChange = { text.value = it },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor =  Color.Red)
)
```

But, there is no such thing in `BasicTextField`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Modifier.background`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary?hl=ru#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).background(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)) in the same way as with any other view that has no custom decoration(as in case of `TextField`)

```
BasicTextField(
    value = text, onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)
)
```